# UPSmon and DLink-320 Sharecenter

Tags: networking, ups, nut

I have a UPS unit attached to the [D-Link 320 ShareCenter](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dns-320-2-bay-sharecenter-network-storage-enclosure), a SOHO 2-bay NAS. I set up the UPS in **Master Mode**. Unfortunately it doesn't supply any information, so I had to literally connect to port using `nc` to port `3493` and issue some commands to get the proper UPS name.

After that I was able to extract the following information:

```
root@galois:~# upsc megatec@192.168.3.6
battery.charge: 100
battery.voltage: 13.70
battery.voltage.high: 13.00
battery.voltage.low: 10.40
battery.voltage.nominal: 12.0
device.type: ups
driver.name: blazer_usb
driver.parameter.pollinterval: 2
driver.parameter.port: auto
driver.version: 2.6.4
driver.version.internal: 0.08
input.current.nominal: 2.0
input.frequency: 50.1
input.frequency.nominal: 50
input.voltage: 224.4
input.voltage.fault: 224.4
input.voltage.nominal: 230
output.voltage: 224.4
ups.beeper.status: enabled
ups.delay.shutdown: 30
ups.delay.start: 180
ups.load: 6
ups.productid: 5161
ups.status: OL
ups.type: offline / line interactive
ups.vendorid: 0665
```

Then I tried to setup `upsmon.conf` in order to monitor the UPS from my Linux host (hostname galois).

```
grep -v "#" /etc/nut/upsmon.conf |sort
DEADTIME 15
FINALDELAY 5
HOSTSYNC 15
MINSUPPLIES 1
MONITOR megatec@192.168.3.6 1 admin <admin-pass> slave
NOCOMMWARNTIME 300
POLLFREQ 5
POLLFREQALERT 5
POWERDOWNFLAG /etc/killpower
RBWARNTIME 43200
SHUTDOWNCMD "/sbin/shutdown -h +0"
```

That's pretty much the default configuration for `slaves`. When I start the service I get the following "ACCESS-DENIED" logs:

```
root@galois:~# service ups-monitor start
[ ok ] Starting NUT - power device monitor and shutdown controller: nut-client.
root@galois:~# tail -n 2 /var/log/syslog
Sep 23 19:12:03 galois upsmon[3997]: Startup successful
Sep 23 19:12:03 galois upsmon[3999]: Login on UPS [megatec@192.168.3.6] failed - got [ERR ACCESS-DENIED]
```

I am sure that I don't need user/password lines in the upsmon line. But I didn't find any way to probe without issuing user and password. Unfortunately [nut-scanner](http://www.networkupstools.org/docs/man/nut-scanner.html) is not in the pre-compiled package and I'm at loss.

Any ideas on how to proceed? The manual of the NAS and their website has no information on how to setup slaves whatsoever.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wonders about this, here are the default UPS accounts for DNS-320 SC NAS:

```
[root]
password = 123
upsmon master

[client]
password = 123
upsmon slave
```